# WinSCP like Sync on linux

Tags: linux, sync, winscp

I'm trying to sync files to an FTP like WinSCP does on linux (continually checking for changes and uploading changed files). Is there such a thing?  
I know of rsync but I don't think that triggering rsync every second is as productive as WinSCP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find any detailed information about "WinSCP continually checking for changes and uploading changed files", but it's hard to believe that it would be more effective than rsync.

If you're looking for a near-real-time solution (i.e. an rsync cron job every minute is not enough for your purpose), something like [lsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/) or [rsync-inotify](http://code.google.com/p/rsync-inotify/) or [pirsyncd](http://code.google.com/p/pirsyncd/) would be suitable. Google "[rsync inotify](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=rsync+inotify)" for more options.

Answer (score 0):

`lftp` was made for that kind of job.  Specifically the 'mirror' option is used to keep two locations in sync. 
This is just a quick version (and unsecure, as it will show the username/password in `ps`) :

```
lftp -u user,password -e 'mirror --reverse --dry-run /source /destination' ftp.server.com
```

There are some examples [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/lftp-mirror-example/) and it's easy to find other examples of automating/scripting it.

Comment: See also here for command line options of lftp:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70058912/9134997